# Keeping $_SESSION in jquery ui tabs, is this actually doable?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, session

So I've been trying to solve this issue for a very long time now, and I'm at my wit's end.

So within a web application I'm working on, the basic idea is that the user logs in, then a session is created in $_SESSION. I can see the contents of it just fine on the index page through `print_r($_SESSION)`.

On the index is some jQuery UI tabs, and those tabs link to some subdirectories like `content/index.php` or `action/index.php` Inside those tabs, trying the aforementioned print statement doesn't return anything at all. It's like it can't see the session at all.

On the index, I have a function called `sec_session_start()` that's been used, and I think there's a possibility of this being an issue. The code for that is this:

```
function sec_session_start() {
  $session_name = 'sample';   // Set a custom session name
  $secure = SECURE;
  // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
  $httponly = true;
  // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
  if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
   header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
   exit();
  }
  // Gets current cookies params.
  $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
  session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
   $cookieParams["path"],
   $cookieParams["domain"],
   $secure,
   $httponly
  );
  // Sets the session name to the one set above.
  session_name($session_name);
  session_start();            // Start the PHP session
  session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
 }
```

Looking at this, the only thing I can think of is `session.use_only_cookies`'s INI setting being the issue for this. Could that be what's blocking me from accessing the session within the tabs? I inherited this and have no clue why it's not letting me access the session regardless.

EDIT 1:

index.php:

```
<?php
  print_r($_SESSION); //prints everything
?>
```

action/index.php or content/index.php retrieved through ajax call via tabs:

```
<?php
  print_r($_SESSION); //returns nothing.
?>
```

EDIT 2:

I figured out the issue. Turns out, the session was stored in a cookie and encrypted. By accessing it via `session_name();` then starting a session on each page, I can see the variables.

Comment: Do you start the sessions in the files content/index.php and action/index.php?

Comment: You are not trying to look at session variables from javascript code are you?

Comment: It was started in /index.php. The one users access first when they log in. To clarify, there's a index.php, a content/index.php, and an action/index.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly No. I know that doesn't work. I'm trying to get a response back in php tags.

Comment: In PHP tags? What are they?

Comment: I think you need to start the session in `index.php` and `action/index.php` etc before doing the `print_r($_SESSION);` In fact you always need to start the session before using it in any script.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Turns out session_start wasn't working because it's a named session. using `session_name('sample')` before starting and trying to output works just fine. That fixes my issue.

Comment: Why are you complicating the session processing by naming them. PHP manages happily without you complicatng things

Comment: Honestly, I inherited this some time back. I'm not actually sure why it's named and the previous developer couldn't be reached for comment.